# saving logout time when the user close the browser

Tags: javascript, save, logout

in my project i want to save the logout time to my db when the user closes the browser ( X button, File-> Exit, right click -> exit, Shift F4 ); i'm using javascript to handle the event with onbeforeunload but this event occurs also with back, forward, refresh events
my question : is there any way to skip those events or another method to achieve this ?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript is limited to the current window object, therefore, it doesn't allow you to access anything further.

Comment: do you another method please ?

Comment: I don't think there is anything that in your case would work. You could setup a server and do long-polling but that would be too overkill.